# WATIR Safari automation Issue

Tags: ruby, safari, watir, browser-automation

I am new to WATIR and I want to automate Safari browser. 
I am using require 'safariwatir' statement in my ruby file.
I am able to open a safari browser window but when I call goto method on my browser object then the result is NIL. It shows FAILED TO OPEN PAGE.
Please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[safariwatir](http://rubygems.org/gems/safariwatir) gem is no longer in active development. The last release was three years ago. You should use [watir-webdriver gem to drive Safari](http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/).

Comment: One more question regarding safariwatir.
if i use both safariwatir and watir-webdriver in my ruby code, then I get some kind of error. 
May be due to the name collision of module WATIR.
How can I get this working? If I want to use both in my same program? Pls help.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use safariwatir at all? As far as I know it just does not work.