# Automation Using Watir

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver, safariwatir

I am trying to automate different browsers using watir, and I am using 'safariwatir' for automating Safari browser. And for firefox, chrome and IE I am using 'watir-webdriver'. 
I am facing some error if I use both 'safariwatir' and web driver in a single program. Is there any way of using these both in a single program. 
Thanks in advance. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already answered in another question that you have asked, [safariwatir is not longer maintained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996929/17469).